# VBA: Hard Coding Dates to X axis in Date format

Tags: vba, charts

I'm having a problem with adding dates to a scatter chart. I'm using a string to add values to a chart's series collection (e.g.: Chart1.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = {date1,date2,date3})

It works great when I format the dates to a number value (e.g.: Format(xDate, "0"), but the X axis shows up as numbers instead of dates.

However, it does NOT work when the dates are left in date format (e.g.: Format(xDate, "MM/DD/YY").

I also tried ("#" & Format(xDate, "MM/DD/YY") & "#") to no avail.

Any Ideas? Hoping it's simple, and I'm just tired from working on my algorithm all day.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the array as something *other than String*?  Like perhaps, as *Date* instead?

Comment: A Date variable wouldn't accept multiple delimited values to create the series. Just figures it out, at least a workaround, will post the answer.

Comment: I often delete rows when I'm filtering though my current data set. If the chart was referencing one of the rows I delete, it gives that annoying reference error, so hard coding the values to the series via string/vba avoids this error.

Comment: So you're aware, `Format` returns a string, regardless of how a number or date is "formatted."  Another alternative that may have worked: `CDate("#" & Format(xDate, "MM/DD/YY") & "#")` to convert from string to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatted the X axis 'Number' to Category: Date (format code: "mm/dd/yyy"), and viola! The chart changes the date number values to the format I wanted to see.